# Wrong DateTime comparing in EF Core when column type date

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have entity class:

```
public class Test
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  
  [Column(TypeName = "date")]
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  public DateTime Date {get; set;}
}
```

I use PostgreSQL. In database `Date` column have type `date`. And without this attribute (`[Column(TypeName = "date")]`) column have type `timestamp`.

Problems starts when i try get entities from dbContext:

```
public List<Test> GetEntities([DataType(DataType.Date)] DateTime date)
{
  var list = _context
      .Where(x => x.Date == date)
      .ToList()

    return list;
}
```

This method always returns empty list. But if in linq write:

```
_context.Where(x => x.Date.Year == date.Year 
                        && x.Date.Month == date.Month 
                        && x.Date.Day == date.Day)
```

It`s works correct and return some value. Why in first version it's always returns empty list?

Comment: Did you try querying like `.Where(x => x.Date == date.Date)`

Comment: @Eldar, yes. It didn`t help

Comment: Can you share the generated SQL from the linq?

Comment: **First version** (when `x.Date.Date == date.Date`):
- WHERE date_trunc('day', r.date) = @__date_Date_0
  
**Second version** (when `x.Date.Year == date.Year` and etc):
- WHERE ((date_part('year', r.date)::INT = @__date_Year_0) AND (date_part('month', r.date)::INT = @__date_Month_1)) AND (date_part('day', r.date)::INT = @__date_Day_2)
  
P.S noticed what in first version in sql use only `day` fields. Strange, but sure i use x.Date.Date == date.Date. No Day :)

Comment: what's the type of `@__date_Date_0` in the generated SQL?

Comment: @ZoharPeled [Parameters=[@__date_Date_0='?' (DbType = Date)]]

Comment: Output sql doesn't look like `x.Date.Date == date.Date` it looks like  `x.Date.Date == date`. You don't need to truncate the left side.

Comment: Please *edit* your question to show the generated SQL. You can then use the code formatting functionality that is sorely lacking in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Dot net <strike>doesn't have a `Date` data type</strike>*, so `.Where(x => x.Date == date)` compares the date **and time** details.
Since you only want to compare the date portion of the `DateTime`, use should make sure the time portion is always equal - you can do that by using the [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-7.0) property (which gives you a `DateTime` value with 00:00:00 as its time portion:

```
public List<Test> GetEntities([DataType(DataType.Date)] DateTime date)
  => _context
        .Where(x => x.Date.Date == date.Date)
        .ToList();
```

*Apperntly, as MindSwipe wrote in his comment, in dot net 6 Microsoft finally added the [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-7.0) struct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't help. I noticed what c# automatically add 00:00:00 for each field, and for entities and for method argument

Comment: Are you sure you've used `.Date` in both sides of the comparison?

Comment: @zohar is correct - you need to fully understand the Answer - read carefully

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes - both sides

Comment: That is strange. this code should guarantee a date-only comparison.

Comment: FWIW starting with .NET 6 .NET *does* have a date only datatype, the aptly named [DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare by date range:

```cs
public List<Test> GetEntities([DataType(DataType.Date)] DateTime date)
{
    var startDate = date.Date;
    var endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);

    var list = _context
       .Where(x => x.Date >= startDate && x.Date < endDate)
       .ToList();

    return list;
}
```